# PXSelect Required parameter Null or blank value

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to lookup all records in a table where an id equals a variable and the order number equals another variable.  When the order number variable is blank or null, I don't get any records even though there are matches in the database.

```
var chkExcepts = new PXSelect<EDImportExcept,
                     Where<EDImportExcept.eDIRefNbr, Equal<Required<EDImportExcept.eDIRefNbr>>,
                      And<Where<EDImportExcept.orderNbr, Equal<Required<EDImportExcept.orderNbr>>,
                      And<Where<EDImportExcept.active, Equal<Required<EDImportExcept.active>>>>>>>>(this);
PXResultset<EDImportExcept> excepts =
             chkExcepts.Select(strDocumentId, ediOrder.OrderNbr ?? "", true);
```

The database column is set as nullable.

The DAC entry is defined as string:

```
#region OrderNbr
public abstract class orderNbr : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
protected string _OrderNbr;
[PXDBString(15, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Order Nbr")]
public virtual string OrderNbr
{
    get
    {
        return this._OrderNbr;
    }
    set
    {
        this._OrderNbr = value;
    }
}
#endregion
```

Why aren't the rows with the matching DocumentId and blank OrderNbr returned?

Answer (score 0):

I moved the coalesce out of the select and set it to a variable and that seems to work.  I was just trying to simplify the code.